# Why is there an error for mixing tabs and spaces but not other PEP8 violations?

Tags: python-3.x, tabs, indentation, pep8

I've been reading [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) but I don't understand why Python3 bothers to single out mixing tabs and spaces with this error message.

> TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

I understand the importance of consistency but an error message that halts execution seems extreme, especially since mixed tabs and spaces doesn't make any difference to the compiler and most good editors support tab/space conversions. On top of that, Python3 doesn't have a problem with you ignoring other PEP conventions (for example using three space indentations instead of four), you won't even get a warning message for it.

So what's the deal, why does Python3 all of sudden treat mixing spaces and tabs like the ultimate evil?

Comment: `especially since mixed tabs and spaces doesn't make any difference to the compiler` - From what I've read, the compiler relies entirely on `\t`. Other whitespace are discrepancies.

Comment: It doesn't "halt execution" so much as refuse to execute. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perfectly well mix tabs and spaces in a python file (though PEP8 says you shouldn't).

*(Stackoverflow prints tab as 4 spaces, example tabs are correct in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hayd/79ee0b1cb507aba943402d4271fbfc9a); test them out yourself!)*

Here's a perfectly valid python function:

```
def foo():
    print("one tab")  # all indentation is one tab.
    if True:
      print("two spaces")
    else:
        print("four spaces")
```

what you can't do is mix tabs and spaces **in the same block**:

```
def foo():
    print("one tab")
        print("eight spaces")
```

This gives a `TabError`.

*Even if these lined up in your text editor.*

---

This is because (roughly) they *may* line up differently in someone else's text editor and look like a different procedure. To give a silly example:

```
def foo():
    while True:
        "we should exit immediately"
        return True  # suppose this was tab indented
```

The last line may look like it lines up with the string, and hence returns immediately, but since it's tab indented perhaps it's lined up with the while (so the while loop never exits). ???

Here lies the ambiguity, and so the parser say no.

---

However, PEP8 says you should just always use 4 spaces, avoiding this ambiguity.

Comment: Okay, I think I see. So if you write mixed tab and spaces code where tab is 4 spaces you'd get misalignment when you paste that into an editor where tab is set to 8 spaces. That might result in a silent error which will ruin your day. Thanks.